# Way to refresh shapefile in Spotfire

Tags: qgis, shapefile, refresh

I am a beginner in working with geospatial data. What I have done so far:

1) I created a map chart visualization in spotfire.

2) I created a shapefile using QGIS.

3) I added the shapefile in the spotfire using Add Data Table -> File

4) I added a feature layer into map chart and used/applied the shapefile    data

So far so good.

But now I guess the shapefile is static data?

How can I refresh the shapefile so that it reflects the changes in the underlying base database? BTW the base or master data is in Oracle.

Versions:
OS - Windows 8.1

QGIS - 3.0.1

Spotfire - 7.11.0

This is the first time I am using either spotfire and qgis.

Comment: I added the "spotfire" tag.